# How to access a property that contains . within the method name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular

For example, I want to access the method [tree.removenode](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/methods#tree-removenode) via the chartContext in angular but I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You use bracket notation:

```js
const something = theObject["the.property"];

// or if it's a method

const something = theObject["the.property"]();
```

See [MDN's page on property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) for more info

Answer (score -1):

If you are passing the method name as a string in variable you can do something like below:

Suppose

```
treeVar = 'tree';
method = 'removenode';
```

First check if its function or not

```
if(typeof chartContext[treeVar][method] === 'function')
```

Then,

```
chartContext[treeVar][method]();
```